# Missing windows installer core.msi in Windows 10

Tags: python

I have been facing problem in installing python because of missing core.msi
How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the entire error?

Comment: Check for running instances of msiexec.exe. If the existing installation process is hung, try installing Python again after rebooting.

https://bugs.python.org/issue25345#msg252565

Answer (score 0):

Use customize installation and pick another location for installation. That fixed my very same issue.